# Insert default content for a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a theme, and I want to give the possibility to insert default content like, posts, pages, categories. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP function that calls a SQL query that writes the defaut content to the relevant tables. The posts, pages and categories can be directly written to the database by the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by importing an XML file, it has dummy posts, pages, and comments. I've found one on Google that you can use, download it [here](http://churchcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/churchcrunch_wordpress_dummy_data.zip)